# paging PageKeyedDataSource swipe to refresh calls loadInitial

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack, android-architecture-paging

I was following https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/PagingWithNetworkSample
I noticed when paging refreshes, swipe to refresh, invalidate() is called and it calls loadInitial which then loads new list. So if I called refresh again and again it always downloads initial data. 
For me I want to refresh page by passing previous key and then update when only new items available. But this use case doesn't seem to be supported by paging library now.

Comment: see [DataSource](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/paging/DataSource), `Updating Paged Data` section in particular

Comment: Are you using paging library with room?

Comment: @pskink The commented document seems to be deprecated now.